# sql developer pop up is not responsive

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

I use SQL Developer version 17.3.1.279.  I try to save a file with File > Save.

[image]

When the 'save' window opens, it is unresponsive, meaning that:

- the 'location' combo is not clickable
- icons such as Desktop or Documents are not clickable
- 'File Name' text area is not clickable
- 'File Type' combo is not clickable
- the close button is not clickable

I  can only move and resize the window. Resizing leads to this:

[image]

After a while, let's say 30 seconds,  all the above fields eventually become clickable , but it is annoying to wait so much. **Any ideas about what might be causing this problem?**

I must mention that this does not seem to be a RAM problem, since other processes like running  a query work really fine, and task manager shows that I still have some extra 2GB of RAM

Comment: Things like this on windows are usually due to stale network shares

Comment: I forgot to mention that the connection is to a database on my local machine. So in this case there is no network latency

Comment: That's not what I meant though. Windows explorer is rubbish, especially in older version of Windows, and can hang when network shares are being crappy. Where the database resides has no bearing on this

Comment: could you please briefly describe the network shares issue? in order for me to know where to investigate further. Perhaps a link describing the issue will be just fine

Comment: I can confirm you were right: on my PC, the drive C is somehow shared in the network, while drive D is on my local harddisk. By default, the save location was C:\something, and it caused sqldeveloper to freeze. Now that I changed it to D:\ , it works normally.